# Nginx Config redirecting to lowercase string instead of original one

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am trying to do a redirect in my nginx config from SubDomain.domain.com to domain.com/SubDomain. The problem I am facing is that when i try SubDomain.domain.com nginx redirects it to domain.com/subdomain and misses the uppercases. How can i achieve that?

Here is my nginx config block:

```
if ($http_host ~* "^(.+)\.domain\.com$") {
   set $subdomain $1;
   rewrite  (.*)  http://domain.com/$subdomain$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is always lowercase.

> $host
>
> This variable is equal to line Host in the header of request or name of the server processing the request if the Host header is not available.
>
> This variable may have a different value from $http_host in such cases: 1) when the Host input header is absent or has an empty value, $host equals to the value of server_name directive; 2)when the value of Host contains port number, $host doesn't include that port number. $host's value is always lowercase since 0.8.17.
>
> $http_HEADER
>
> The value of the HTTP request header HEADER when converted to lowercase and with 'dashes' converted to 'underscores', e.g. $http_user_agent, $http_referer...;

Source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24host

Comment: Also all browsers will lowercase hostname before request so normally you will never get request with uppercase letters in hostname.